# React error: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am making a calendar with React but this problem show when I try to run it:

> yarn start "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Calendar`."
my Calendar.jsx code:

```
import React, {  useRef,useState } from "react";
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react' 
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import AddEventModal from "./AddEventModal";


function Calendar ()  {
  const[modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const calendarRef =useRef(null);
  const onEventAdded = event =>{
    let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();
    calendarApi.addEvent(event);
    
  }
  return(
    <section>
      <button>Add Event to the Calendar</button>
      <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        />
      <AddEventModal isOpen={modalOpen}
        onClose={() => setModalOpen(false)}
        onEventAdded={event => onEventAdded(event)}/>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Calendar
```

Comment: Could you add the calling parent component along with the `AddEventModal `?

Comment: could you also post `AddEventModal`?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue (but wasn't using a modal). Turns out the import URL of the component was wrong. That is the error message React v17 gives you when the file's URL is wrong apparently. Might wanna check your import?